# how to assign subscribed response to class variable in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this following method,

```
 public getResults(page: Page ): Observable<PagedData<CorporateEmployee>> {
            var companyData1:Observable<PagedData<CorporateEmployee>>;
            this.getUsersData().subscribe(users=>{
                    //companyData1.push(users['info']); 
                    alert('local func2');
                    companyData1 = Observable.of(users['info']).map(data => this.getPagedData(page,users['info'])); 
                });
            alert('local func1');
            //alert(this.companyData);
            return companyData1;
            // this.getUsers();
        }
```

and one more method for db values,

```
getUsersData():Observable<any[]>{
        alert('called func');
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl+'get_users_data',this.header)
        .map((response:Response)=><any[]>response.json())
        .do(data=>{console.log(data['info']);this.companyData = data['info'];})
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Here, What else is wrong . I could not assign it to a class variable. I want to subscribe the json response to my class variable. even if i assign, it does not hold any thing. while alert that variable, it display 'undefined'.

Comment: The getResults function returns a undefined because it is still not assigned when the function returns. companyData1 is assigned within the subscribe which is async

Comment: The getResults is a service method which is invoked by the following code,

Comment: `setPage(pageInfo){
    console.log(pageInfo);
    this.page.pageNumber = pageInfo.offset;
    this.serverResultsService.getResults(this.page).subscribe(pagedData => {
      this.page = pagedData.page;
      this.rows = pagedData.data;
      //alert(JSON.stringify(pagedData.data));
    });
  }`

Comment: Hi, i made a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OxjJnSp89BjYQitR35OZ?p=preview
Not sure what  your map supposed to do so i left it out 
"rsponse.json()" a function?

Comment: Thank you  @Carbosound1. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Carbosound1 , please make a plunker example for server pagination in angular 2 with db results.

Comment: I added my plunker as an answer to your question.
When it comes to pagination thats a different question.
you can make an api call with arguments:
api/users?page=1

Answer (score 0):

to subscribe do something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this._userService)
    this._userService.getUsersData().subscribe(data => {
      this.d = data;
    }, error => console.log(error));
```

service:

```
public getUsersData():Observable<any[]>{
        return this._http.get('response.json')
        .do(data=>{
          this.x = data;
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OxjJnSp89BjYQitR35OZ?p=preview

Comment: `@Injectable()
export class MockServerResultsService {
    
    private doctors = [];
    
    constructor(private _http:Http){
        this._http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
        .map((data) => data.json())
        .subscribe((data) => {
          this.doctors.push(data);
          console.log(this.doctors);
          alert(JSON.stringify(this.doctors));// displays data
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.doctors));// displays '[]'
    }   `   What else is wrong in my subscription. while alert i got as commented. **@Carbosound1**

Comment: `return Observable.of(this.doctors).map(data => this.getPagedData(page));`  I want the above code result of doctors for input to the getPagedData method. But the doctors variable of the service class does not hold anything except inside of the subscription block.